# Mask passwords in String

Tags: regex, string, replace, substring, masking

I have been wondering quite a bit on String functions such as replace().

My objective is simple. I have a logger, that logs strings into a text file, that contains passwords which needs to be masked before writing it to the log file.

For example:

```
str = "-field_value=userId=1,-field_value=password=pass123,-field_value=location=London,-field_value=day=Tuesday,-field_value=emailPassword=pass123,-field_value=fbPassword=pass1234";
```

Which approach would be the best in this case? The string may or may not end with any password **"field_value"**.

I need to mask all the occurring "Passwords" with their exact length, in this string to get the following output:

```
str = "-field_value=userId=1,-field_value=password=*******,-field_value=location=London,-field_value=day=Tuesday,-field_value=emailPassword=*******,-field_value=fbPassword=********";
```

Which would be a more suitable option to use? Normal string handling (using substrings/replaceAll/indexOf) or StringBuilder functions?

Also, how effective is using Regular Expressions in this case? I've never used Regex extensively, so I have little idea on using it for this scenario.

Comment: I am currently using Java for this use case. Though a solution in C# would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `String.replaceAll(regex, replace)` method, to search for `password` or `emailPassword` etc and did the masking. Not sure, if that's the most ideal method to do the masking in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is C#, but this answer is valid for many other languages.

You must not have passwords in clear text. Just now you do. So that is a huge security concern and it doesn't matter if you put "*" instead of the password. It is there in memory and little skill is needed to extract passwords from memory (given attacker has access to the machine).

A standard approach is that you only store password hash and salt. Now the problem would be how do you convert a password into the hash and how do you securely dispose original password. For this purpose you should use [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) which encrypts the password string in memory and securely removes it from memory when it is no longer needed.

To give a direct answer to your question: you do not use any approach to replace a password character with a star. Any approach in this case is insecure.